# Drop multi-indexed rows of a DataFrame based on 'AND' condition between levels

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I want to be able to drop rows from a multi-indexed dataframe object using multiple level criteria (with a logical AND joining the criteria).

Consider the pandas dataframe object given by:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1,'x'],[2,'x'],[1,'y'],[2,'y']],
                   index=pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['A','B'],['a','b']],
                                       labels=[[0,1,0,1],[0,1,1,0]],
                                       names=['idx0','idx1']))
```

`print(df)` outputs:

```
           0  1
idx0 idx1      
A    a     1  x
B    b     2  x
A    b     1  y
B    a     2  y
```

I wish to eliminate the row where `'idx0'=='A'` **and** `'idx1'=='a'`, so the end result is:

```
           0  1
idx0 idx1      
B    b     2  x
     a     2  y
A    b     1  y
```

It seems to me as if this cannot be done with the `df.drop()` method. A 'roundabout' way which gives the correct result is to do:

```
df = pd.concat([df.drop(labels='A',level=0),df.drop(labels='a',level=1)])
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

But I figure that there has to be a better way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To address your question regarding `.drop()` - just pass the `MultiIndex` labels as `tuple`:

```
df.drop(('A', 'a'))

           0  1
idx0 idx1      
B    b     2  x
A    b     1  y
B    a     2  y
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) method for index and take opposite to what are you selecting with `~`:

```
In [85]: df.index.isin([('A','a')])
Out[85]: array([ True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [86]: df[~df.index.isin([('A','a')])]
Out[86]:
           0  1
idx0 idx1
B    b     2  x
A    b     1  y
B    a     2  y
```

**Timing:**

```
In [95]: %timeit df.drop(('A','a'))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.33 ms per loop

In [96]: %timeit df[~df.index.isin([('A','a')])]
1000 loops, best of 3: 457 us per loop
```

So drop is almost 3x times slower then with `isin` solution.